# Xcode Application Loader

Tags: xcode4, installation, application-loader

I am a novice when it comes to apps but i have managed to write one, test it, debug it, install it onto my Iphone. I'm now on the final step upload it through application loader...

my problem is i can't get application loader to install. i have downloaded it,  run the .dmg, this creates a new device on my system with the file applicationloader.pkg. I run this and it runs me through the installation, i have entered my admin authority, it says installation complete.

But it doesn't have the program anywhere. i have looked in Applications, searched in the finder and i can not locate where the application loader is.

1 - is there a reason why it wouldn't be installing properly?
2 - is there a way to download a previous version  (current is 2.7) to try that
3 - is there a way of uploading without the application loader?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest Xcode installed on your machine, go to the Xcode menu item/Developer Tools and open the Application Loader. If you are working with Xcode there is no need to use the application loader though. Every step you need to bring your app into iTunes connect can be done via Xcode. The steps are Archive (for Release), select the archive - validate it (you mast have prepared your app in iTunes Connect (must be in the status ready for upload) and the submit it to the store.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, i knew it would be obvious. Thank you again.

Comment: Thats why we are here. To be a good stackoverflow citizen you should mark the best answer as accepted.